# Fatal error: Call to a member function setData() on boolean

Tags: magento-1.9

Having issue with this code.

```
$table2 = Mage::getModel('tag/tag_properties');
            $table2->setData(array('tag_id'=>$lat,'store_id'=>1,'base_popularity'=>0));
         $table2->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like following

```
$table2 = Mage::getModel('tag/tag_properties');
$table2->setTagId($lat);
$table2->setStoreId(1);
$table2->setBasePopularity(0);
$table2->save();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but its not working.  Now show given below error.
Fatal error: Call to a member function setTagId() on boolean in

Comment: Replace with with $table2 = Mage::getModel('tag/properties'); and then try.

Comment: No, Its not working with $table2 = Mage::getModel('tag/properties');  this too.

Comment: Have you create model.? Or  tag_id is auto increment in db.? if it's yes then you don't need to set it. It'll automatic create.

Comment: Yes, Model is already created and no its not auto increment, this field is defined in 'tag properties' table and have foreign key for 'tag' tag_id field.

Comment: Can you please post your config.xml file

Answer (score 0):

setTagId() its datatype may be boolean and $lat which value you have to stored.

Comment: No, I have checked in database table. 'tag_id' is int(10)

Comment: primary key set or foreign key set is there please checked up.

Comment: Yes, foreign key is set with tag_properties table with table tag tag_id but how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: remove the foreign key or get collection of tag table and check $lat is match tag_id  then save it.